# Formatted Text (Word Art style) Dynamically Updated in PowerPoint 2010?

Tags: powerpoint-2010

I am working on developing weather graphics in PowerPoint 2010 for our online weather forecast operation.  I am trying to update formatted text (Word Art type formatting, such as text outlining, shadowing, etc.,) automatically within a PowerPoint slide.

[Click for example map](https://scontent-ord1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/10256563_590364334395826_7012719256559028626_n.png?oh=e1e90a1f46c0843cef39b528a9b8456e&oe=561AA40D)

I have looked through the numerous articles both here and elsewhere on how to dynamically update text from Excel cells in PowerPoint and other methods, but I can't find any way of updating text such as the temperature values in the map above, while still keeping the visual formatting (which is absolutely **crucial** for this project).  Is there any way to do this in text format, or would I just be better off developing the system so that the text values on the map are actually auto-updating images, so that the formatting is preserved?  If that is the route I must take, I am fine with that.  I just need pointed in the right direction.  Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Thank you for your time...

Comment: I suspect what you're running into is this: If you change the .Text property of the shape, you lose any formatting.  But PPT's .TextRange object has a .Replace method you can use instead. It does a pretty good job of preserving existing formatting.  Now if the text has more than one set of formatting changes applied to it (eg. first character bolded, remainder some other format), things get way more complicated.